# Memory errors in shuffle phase (lost task...) when processing a very big graph with Pregel algorithm

Tags: scala, memory, spark-graphx

I am executing the **Pregel algorithm with Spark GraphX in Scala.**

My graph contains 1 million of nodes, and 5 millons of edges between them.
My cluster is very powerful, with several servers for BigData, with 256GB of memory each.

I have a "**Java Heap Space error**" in a **shuffle phase** during the execution, after more than 20 minutes of processing: **task lost**...
I am going to analyse these parameters:

- Analysis of the way I **load** the Graph and its **persistence (StorageLevel)**
- Analysis of **memory** used by: **nodes, edges and messages sent**
- Analysis of the parameters set in Spark when using the spark-submit command: number of **executors**, **memory/vcores** per executor, **serialization**...

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion of my analysis and the optimizations I have used:

- **Parameters** of Spark used in **spark-submit**: **90%** used of available YARN **memory** in the cluster. I used **3 vcores/executor** and **3 executors per physical server**. I run it with KryoSerializer, to reduce the space of the data stored.
- **Graph - RDDs of nodes and edges:** previously, I created and stored the RDDs of nodes and edges in **HDFS**, in 1000 files by using coalesce, so that the data is saved uniformly, although it lasts a long time.
- **Graph - Loading:** from existing RDD files in HDFS.
- **Graph - Nodes and Edges:** loaded correctly. Their attributes in scala are only the ones I use (5 attributes each) and with the minimal use of memory (Integers), with no auxiliary attributes.
- **Graph - Messages** merged in the **mergeMsg** method: I combine the 2 messages, by using my own formula (related to the target of my project).
- **Graph - vprog:** the nodes gather all the information received in the messages and save it in a List of "known good info" inside each node. That info is used to create the
- **Graph - Messages** sent in **sendMsg** method: each node uses its info (List of known good info and its other attributes) to create the messages to be sent. Also, to reduce the number of messages, I filtered the messages that were not useful, in order not to send them in the Iterator.

I discovered **MY MAIN PROBLEM**: the **List** inside each node that saves the "known good info" is **immutable**.

**SOLUTION: I should use ListBuffer (mutable)**. Also, I should use the method **.append()** instead of .++(), because this one creates a new instance of the List.

More info of collections in scala: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics

The performance now is more than 10 times faster and the memory errors do not appear now.

Comment: Also, I used the strategy StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK when loading the graph.

Comment: Each list has 10-20 items after 4 iterations in Pregel